# Typeorm Listener trigger another entity that have relation with

Tags: postgresql, jpa, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I am using Typeorm and I want to trigger the listener of my entity if an entity that have relation with has been updated relation, here is an example:

```
@Entity()
export class User {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column({ type: 'character varying'})
Name: string;

@Column({ type: 'character varying'})
email: string;

@OneToMany(() => Photo, (photo) => photo.user)
photos: Photo[]

}
```

and

```
@Entity()
export class Photo {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column({ type: 'integer'})
size: string;

@Column({ type: 'character varying'})
userEmail: string;

@OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.photo)
@JoinColumn()
user: User

@BeforeUpdate()
async emailChange() {

  try{
    let repo: any = await Object.values(require(`../../../repository/User.repository`),)[0];
    const userRepository:any = getCustomRepository(repo);
    const result = await userRepository.findOne({ where: {'id' : this.user}});
    this.userEmail=result.email
  }catch(err){
    console.log('emailChange Error =====> ',err);
  }

 }

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

> Typeorm: 0.2.45
> Postgresql: 13

Comment: what is a listner? do you mean listener?

Comment: yes, I forgot an 'e'